# UDP socket unable to send packet to DHCP address

Tags: c#, sockets, dhcp, udpclient

I have created simple UDP socket connection to send data between local network. The connection is of two types : peer to peer and group broadcast. Below is my class :
Peer to peer server:

```
public class CandyCaneUdpServer
{
    Socket sck;
    EndPoint LocalEP;
    EndPoint RemoteEP;
    int port = 80;
    IAsyncResult oldAsyncResult;

    public event EventHandler<MessageObject> RaiseMessageReceivedEvent;

    public CandyCaneUdpServer()
    {
        sck = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
        sck.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
        sck.ExclusiveAddressUse = false;
        LocalEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(UdpUtility.GetLocalIP()), port);
        RemoteEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port);
    }

    public void Serve()
    {
        sck.Bind(LocalEP);
        byte[] _buffer = new byte[1500];
        oldAsyncResult = sck.BeginReceiveFrom(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref RemoteEP, new AsyncCallback(MessageCallBack), _buffer);
    }

    private void MessageCallBack(IAsyncResult aResult)
    {
        int size = sck.EndReceiveFrom(aResult, ref RemoteEP);
        if (size > 0)
        {
            byte[] receivedData;
            receivedData = (byte[])aResult.AsyncState;
            MessageObject obj;
            IFormatter f = new BinaryFormatter();
            using (MemoryStream s = new MemoryStream(receivedData))
            {
                obj = (MessageObject)f.Deserialize(s);
            }
            OnRaiseMessageReceivedEvent(obj);
        }

        var _buffer = new byte[1500];
        oldAsyncResult = sck.BeginReceiveFrom(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref RemoteEP, new AsyncCallback(MessageCallBack), _buffer);
    }

    protected virtual void OnRaiseMessageReceivedEvent(MessageObject e)
    {
        EventHandler<MessageObject> handler = RaiseMessageReceivedEvent;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Below is peer to peer client(sender):

```
public class CandyCaneUdpClient
{
    Socket sck;
    EndPoint RemoteEP;

    public CandyCaneUdpClient(string RemoteIP, int RemotePort)
    {
        sck = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
        sck.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
        sck.ExclusiveAddressUse = false;
        RemoteEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(RemoteIP), RemotePort);
    }

    public void Send(int MessageId, string Message, __MessageObjectType t = __MessageObjectType.P2P)
    {
        byte[] msg;
        msg = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Message);
        var obj = new MessageObject()
        {
            Id = MessageId,
            Type = t,
            SourceIP = UdpUtility.GetLocalIP(),
            TargetIP = ((IPEndPoint)RemoteEP).Address.ToString(),
            SentTime = DateTime.Now,
            Message = Message
        };
        IFormatter f = new BinaryFormatter();
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            f.Serialize(ms, obj);
            var msgByte = ms.ToArray();
            sck.SendTo(msgByte, msgByte.Length, SocketFlags.None, RemoteEP);
        }
    }
}
```

The code is working fine for all ether-net machines. When a wifi client is connected, the wireless pc can send data but not receive data. When I examine the IP, ether-net client has IP of 192.168.211.---. whereas wireless pc has an IP of 192.168.0.---. I wonder if DHCP address causes the issue. The group chat works fine.

```
public class CandyCaneUdpGroupChatListener
    {
        UdpClient listener;

        IPAddress routerBindIP;
        readonly int routerBindPort = UdpUtility.GroupChatDefinedPort();
        EndPoint routerEP, senderEP;

        public event EventHandler<MessageObject> RaiseMessageReceivedEvent;

        public CandyCaneUdpGroupChatListener()
        {
            routerBindIP = IPAddress.Parse(UdpUtility.GroupChatRouterBindAddress());
            routerEP = new IPEndPoint(routerBindIP, routerBindPort);
            senderEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(UdpUtility.GetLocalIP()), routerBindPort);


            listener = new UdpClient();

            listener.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);

            listener.ExclusiveAddressUse = false;
            listener.Client.Bind(senderEP);
            listener.JoinMulticastGroup(routerBindIP);

            var _buffer = new byte[1500];

            listener.Client.BeginReceiveFrom(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref routerEP,
                new AsyncCallback(ReceiveMessage), _buffer);
        }

        private void ReceiveMessage(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            if (listener == null) return;
            if (listener.Client == null) return;
            int size = listener.Client.EndReceiveFrom(result, ref routerEP);

            if (size > 0)
            {
                byte[] receivedData;
                receivedData = (byte[])result.AsyncState;
                MessageObject obj;
                IFormatter f = new BinaryFormatter();
                using (MemoryStream s = new MemoryStream(receivedData))
                {
                    obj = (MessageObject)f.Deserialize(s);
                    //if (obj.SourceIP == UdpUtility.GetLocalIP()) return;
                }
                MessageReceived(obj);
            }

            var _buffer = new byte[1500];
            listener.Client.BeginReceiveFrom(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref routerEP,
                new AsyncCallback(ReceiveMessage), _buffer);
        }

        protected virtual void MessageReceived(MessageObject e)
        {
            EventHandler<MessageObject> handler = this.RaiseMessageReceivedEvent;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, e);
            }
        }

        public void Disconnect()
        {
            listener.DropMulticastGroup(routerBindIP);           
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out how you have your wired and wireless network subnets laid out.  It looks like you've got two different DHCP servers working here - one for the wired network and another one for the wireless network.

Make sure that your network routers are configured such that a host on one subnet can communicate with a host on the other subnet.

To determine if a host on one subnet can communicate with a host on the other subnet, you could use the network trace route utility or the ping utility.

On Windows, trace route is implemented as the `tracert.exe` application, which you should find in the `C:\Windows\System32` directory.

Suppose you're on the Ethernet-attached client, you might execute it with the following command line to attempt to trace the route to the wireless PC (suppose it has the address 192.168.0.104):

```
C:> \Windows\System32\tracert.exe 192.168.0.104
```

You should see output that looks similar to this:

```
Tracing route to 192.168.0.104
over a maximum of 30 hops:

1    1 ms     1 ms    <1 ms    192.168.211.54
... (possibly other entries her)
2    1 ms     1 ms     1 ms    192.168.0.104

Trace complete.
```

If the trace fails to complete, it's an indicate that your network traffic cannot get to the machine you're trying to trace to.

Be aware that if `tracert` fails it's not a 100% indication of connectivity failure.  It may be an indication that ICMP traffic is being blocked by a firewall or the destination machine is not responding to ICMP requests.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have access to devices.

Comment: Tried tracing. Ether-net attached tracing machine results **Request Timed Out** while tracing from wireless connected laptop is a success. I don't understand why the connection can only go one direction.

Comment: Perhaps this is a firewall configuration issue. Ensure that all ports required for your application to communicate are opened on both machines.